# How do I improve quality of debug data when my app crashes in the wild?

Tags: android, remote-debugging

I had my first NullPointerExceptions in my app and it showed up on the Developer Console.

While I was starting to ask for advice here I realised what the problem was, but it brought to the front of my mind something that's been bothering me for some time - how to make it as easy as possible to debug my code when the only thing I have access to is the developer console and the stack traces present there.

In other words, is there anything I can do as a developer to improve the feedback I get when my app crashes in the wild? Maybe it's Google Analytics, maybe the Instrumentation classes, but there must be a better way to get more context to help me debug my app when I don't have access to the user or their device for debugging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use ACRA http://code.google.com/p/acra/

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly what I was looking for and it's flexible enough that you can add additional data to the crash report.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some application logging turned on, then you can send those logs as well using http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/.  This will give you invaluable context about what the user was actually doing in the period leading up to when the crash happened.